# Using "continue" in while loop, skips over scanf("%d", var)

Tags: c

So I'm using visual studios for my C program.

The while loop starts with a prompt and a scanf, if the user puts in a non-digit response, the switch/case in the loop goes to default. This prints an error and "continues" the loop.

The issue is that when the loop continues to the next iteration it skips the "scanf" altogether, and then infinitely loops through the default case. I've searched for hours but can't seem to find a solution.

My goal is to skip the code after the switch/case, and then go back to the beginning. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
while (userInput != 'N' && userInput != 'n') {

    printf("Enter input coefficients a, b and c: "); // prompt user input
    scanf_s("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c); // look for and store user input

    /* ----- Break up the quadratic formula into parts -----*/

    inSqRoot = (pow(b, 2) - (4.0 * a * c)); // b^2 - 4ac
    absInSqRoot = abs((pow(b, 2) - (4.0 * a * c))); // absolute value of b^2 - 4ac
    denom = 2.0 * a; // get denomiator 2.0 * a
    negB = -1.0 * b; // take negative of b

    /*------ Determine number of roots -------*/

    if (!isdigit(a) || !isdigit(b) || !isdigit(c)) {

        rootNum = 4;

    }  // end if

    else if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) {

        rootNum = 0;
    } // end if

    else if (inSqRoot == 0) {

        rootNum = 1;
    } // end if

    else if (inSqRoot > 0) {

        rootNum = 2;
    } // end if

    else if (inSqRoot < 0) {

        rootNum = 3;

    } // end if


    /*------ Begin switch case for rootNum ------*/

    switch (rootNum) {

    case 0: // no roots

        printf("The equation has no roots.\n");
        break;

    case 1: // one root

        root1 = (-b + sqrt(inSqRoot)) / denom;

        printf("The equation has one real root.\n");
        printf("The root is: %.4g\n", root1);
        break;

    case 2: // two roots

        root1 = (-b + sqrt(inSqRoot)) / denom;
        root2 = (-b - sqrt(inSqRoot)) / denom;

        printf("The equation has two real roots.\n");
        printf("The roots are: %.4g and %.4g\n", root1, root2);
        break;

    case 3: // imaginary roots

        printf("The equation has imaginary roots.\n");
        printf("The roots are: %.1g + %.4gi and %.1g - %.4gi \n", negB / denom, sqrt(absInSqRoot) / denom, negB / denom, sqrt(absInSqRoot) / denom);
        break;

    default:
        printf("ERROR: The given values are not valid for a quadratic equation.\n");
        continue;
    }

    printf("Enter Y if you want to continue or N to stop the program: ");
    scanf_s("%*c%c", &userInput);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `continue` means "break current execution and start the looped code from the begining". So it is a "short-circuit" for loops. `break` on the other hand will exit looped block. Here you could simply skip `conitinue` and your scanf_s will be executed.

Comment: In the `case` statemets however,`break` breaks current `case` not the outer loop

Comment: Well my goal is to skip the code after the switch case if the default case is activated. Then go back to the top and ask the user to re-input the integer values.

Comment: `scanf_s("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);` causes the input to be read as integers not as an ascii character. So calling `isdigit(a)` does not make sense because `a` is not an ascii character. For example, if the user enters "1" then the value of `a` will be 1 and not 31 (the ascii character for `'1'`). In that case `isdigit` will return false when you want it to be true.

Comment: This might sound like a ridiculous question at first -- but if my hunch is correct it will make sense shortly. How sure are you that scanf_s isn't being called?  When you're stuck in the infinite loop, are you by chance seeing "Enter input coefficients a, b and c: " printed repeatedly?

Comment: @AbigayilBayBrown reconsider using `do...while` loop. It suits your needst much more as the condition will be checked after every iteration insteed of prior

Comment: You're right about the isdigit(), that actually ended up not working for the purpose of the progam.

Comment: @TimothyJohns yeah I am seeing it print repeatedly in the infinite loop, but when I take out the "continue," the scanf works fine.

Comment: It "works fine" because you are reading in the bad input chars in the other scanf after the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scanf isn't actually skipped, it just reads the same bad input over and over.  You can use the return value from scanf to see how many arguments were read.  In the case of bad input, it will be less than 3.  To flush the bad input you can call a function like this

```
void flushInput() {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

and add a call to flushInput in your default case

```
default:
    printf("ERROR: The given values are not valid for a quadratic equation.\n");
    flushInput();
    continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general reading and validating user input is essential to writing a well-behaving application, when user input is involved. Users may submit input that's not "perfect", and your application should check this.

scanf() may not be the best choice, because it's a steam input, not console input function and does not behave the desired way:

- Treats blanks and newlines the same
- will only return if all variables are read and assigned, or an end-of-file character (Ctrl+Z) is encountered.

So my suggestion is to use the console-I/0 function of choice instead, which is `gets()` (or its "safe" form `gets_s()`). This one behaves as desired, as it reads exactly a whole line of text, and returns when Enter is pressed (scanf() may even read arguments from the next line).

Then use `sscanf()`, it's like scanf(), but reads the variables from a buffer instead, and returns the number of variables read and assigned. You can use "%d %d &d %s" as the format string, so as to check whether the user has input exactly 3 variables, not fewer or even... more (the fourth variable would be a dummy string, used only to make sscanf() return more than 3 if the user submits garbled input).